# difference between PLSA and LDA

Tags: statistics, probability

What is the difference between Probabilistic Latent Semantic Analysis(pLSA) and Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA)?

Comment: Welcome to SciCompSE. Could you please provide some more context to your question? This will help in getting an answer